# In BGP What is an AS-segment? How is it different from an AS-path?

Tags: bgp, bgp-ipv6

Can a single NLRI have more than one AS-Segment in an AS-path?
Is AS-segment same as a AS-Number in a AS-path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS-PATHs contain one or more segments.

1. Yes, if the AS=PATH includes both an AS-Sequence and an AS-SET.
2. Not exactly.  The segment includes the type (sequence or set), length, and value (list of ASNs).  In other words the segment can include more than one ASN.